# In R, how to calculate KL Distance between two vectors of strings?

Tags: r

If I have 2 vectors of strings like:

```
> list1 = c("cat", "dog", "cat", "rabbit", "dog", "cat")
> list2 = c("dog", "rabbit", "dog", "mouse", "dog", "rabbit", "cat")
```

I can get distributions for each.  For example:

```
> dist1 = table(list1)/length(list1)
> dist2 = table(list2)/length(list2)
> dist1; dist2

list1
      cat       dog    rabbit 
0.5000000 0.3333333 0.1666667 
list2
      cat       dog     mouse    rabbit 
0.1428571 0.4285714 0.1428571 0.2857143
```

How do I calculate the KL Distance between these two distributions?  (Using dist2 as the baseline.)

The KL functions I've seen (e.g., kl.dist) require vectors of the same length.

Comment: This measure (Kullback-Leibler) for discrete distributions uses the log of the quotient for each pair of probabilities. Whichever way you look at it (since mouse probability is zero in list1) you either want the log of zero or the log of division by zero, both of which are useless here. All probabilities must be non-zero for this distance to be calculated.

Comment: Actually, only the base distribution (dist2 here) needs to be non-zero.  p * log(p/q) is defined to be zero if p is 0.  That's why I use dist2 as the baseline.  In any case, I'm still interested in how to calculate the KL distance.

Comment: Why not just make your distributions of equal length and set the distribution to 0 for missing values?

Comment: Ok. Then I think you want to simply remove any entries that don't exist in both lists and run the standard kl.dist function on the truncated vectors.

Comment: Thanks Ian, Gladwell.  So how do I create a distribution based on a list of elements (e.g., "cat", "dog", ...)?  Table doesn't seem to do that. 
  I can loop through each element one by one, but that would take too long for a long list of string vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will produce a data frame with one column with the distribution for each vector strings:

```
library(dplyr)

list1 <- c("cat", "dog", "cat", "rabbit", "dog", "cat")
list2 <- c("dog", "rabbit", "dog", "mouse", "dog", "rabbit", "cat")

dist1 <- table(list1)/length(list1)
dist2 <- table(list2)/length(list2)

BothDist <- full_join(as.data.frame(dist1),as.data.frame(dist2), by = c("list1" = "list2")) 
BothDist[is.na(BothDist)] <- 0

BothDist
```

Comment: For full_join, is there a way to refer to columns without a name?

Comment: I may be mistaken​ but I believe you either need to provide column names or have the two data frames share the same column name you wish to join on.  This should not cause any problems because you can always rename your columns.